# why does String is greater than number in comparison in bash

Tags: bash, shell

here is my shell script.I have no idea why String is greater than number.

```
if [ a \> 11111111 ];then
 echo "string is greater"
else
echo "number is greater"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html

STRING1 > STRING2
                 True if STRING1 sorts after STRING2 lexicographically.

It is to do with lexicographical comparison & per `test` `man` page it just comes out with result on whichever is greater & **not** by *actual* comparison

So

```
if [ a > 11111111 ];then echo "string is greater" fi

if [ 11111111 > a ];then echo "string is greater" fi
```

Both of them prints `string is greater` only!!

Comment: i was not clear still after reading the link you posted.Why is any one of the two Strings greater than the other according to your answer.what does determine the sort of lexicographical on the above example?

Comment: Lexicographical comparison is an operation where two strings are compared alphabetically by comparing the characters in a string sequentially from left to right.


http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html : `>   is greater than, in ASCII alphabetical order `

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASCIIDEF